# Selenium is not filling in password attribute on form

Tags: java, selenium

I have a very simple script for selenium to try and debug an issue I'm having. All I do is fill in the username, then fill in the password, then check that the password I typed is in the password field. The reason I'm doing this is that I can't get it to authenticate in general, consistently getting 'password incorrect issue' when it's the correct password.

The form html:

```
<input class="inp" id="userName" name="userName" type="text" />             
<input class="inp" id="password" name="password" type="password" /> 
<label for="rememberMe">remember</label> 
<input class="rem" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" />        
<input name="submit" id="loginSubmit" value="go" type="image" src="http://terra/wp-content/themes/ecobee/images/arrow-right_16x16.gif" />
```

And the Java created from my Selenium script:

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class toso extends SeleneseTestCase {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://terra/");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testToso() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("userName", "cw@qa.com");
        selenium.type("password", "qqqqqqqq");
        verifyEquals("qqqqqqqq", selenium.getValue("password"));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

This throws a `expected "" to match glob "qqqqqqqq" (had transformed the glob into regexp "qqqqqqqq")` suggesting the the password field is filled in. I also watched the test complete on slow mode, the script fills in the username, but not the password field.

Comment: have you tried using a different descriptor for the password field?

Comment: @rs79 yes that has crossed my mind, BUT the descriptor is working. I added a `selenium.highlight("password")` to the above test and it highlights the corrects bubble. You think this could still be the issue?

Comment: i would recommend trying a css identifier for the password field in the selenium.getValue(...);

Comment: @rs79 would this explain why when I watch the code execute there is no text put into the password field?

Comment: i tried your code and didn't find any problem with it at my end. another thing i would try is to perhaps, slow the execution speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very strange, never really found out why this method won't work for this particular field, it works everywhere else on the page.

The way I solved this was

```
char[] password = {'p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d'};
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    selenium.keyPress("password", password[i]);
}
```