# how to identify a Text field in Selenium IDE using class attribute

Tags: selenium

Say i have a text area:`

```
<body contenteditable="true" class="html-editor portlet portlet-blogs cke_show_borders" spellcheck="false"><p><br type="_moz"></p></body>`
```

As you see there is no id so i want to idenify it using class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
css=tag.class

tag=HTML tage of the element

class=class of the element

type this in target

css=body.html-editor portlet portlet-blogs cke_show_borders
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521602/selenium-get-element-class-and-text?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175246/how-to-add-selenium-test-coverage-for-jquery-autocompleter-text-field?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989512/selenium-how-to-click-on-the-calendar-date-by-text-inside-the-dv-attribute?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102937/typing-characters-in-rich-text-editor-using-selenium-ide?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509719/selenium-is-not-filling-in-password-attribute-on-form?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
//body[@class='html-editor portlet portlet-blogs cke_show_borders']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find Xpath of the text field, use Xpath to identify the text field and selenium ide you have to write following command

```
type|Xpath of text field | your content
```

you can install firepath plugin in FF browser and take xpath of text box through firebug,
EG: `//*[@id='search']/div/input`

Comment: @Kameron please check my answer help you or not.