# selenium - how to click on the calendar date by text inside the <dv> attribute

Tags: java, selenium

The problem I'm having is that I don't want to specify the absolute xpath when clicking on 17 or 18 - rather I want to be able to click by specifying the text. But the link text looks for `<a>` or `href` attribute in html and I have `<td>` attribute that I need help on to how to click on it by somehow specifying a text.

Here is the sample html code that resides inside the table:

```
<td class="centerText day" data-bind="click: function(){$root.dayClicked($parent.days()[$index()])}, text: $parent.days()[$index()].day, css: { currentMonth: !$parent.days()[$index()].currentMonth, currentDay: $parent.days()[$index()].currentDay, selectedDay: $parent.days()[$index()].selectedDay }">17</td>

<td class="centerText day" data-bind="click: function(){$root.dayClicked($parent.days()[$index()])}, text: $parent.days()[$index()].day, css: { currentMonth: !$parent.days()[$index()].currentMonth, currentDay: $parent.days()[$index()].currentDay, selectedDay: $parent.days()[$index()].selectedDay }">18</td>
```

Here is my selenium code:

```
            //click the calendar button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnTradeDate']")).click();

             //go through the calendar table to navigate through each cell
     WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id("transactionGridControls"));  
     List<WebElement> rows=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));  
      List<WebElement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));  

      for (WebElement cell: rows){  
       //Select 17th Date   
       if (cell.getText().equals("17")){  
       cell.findElement(By.linkText("17")).click(); //need help on this 
       break;
```

Comment: The problem is that the HTML you have isn't an anchor tag, it's a td that acts like an anchor when clicked.  You should be able to use `cell.click()` in place of the `cell.findElement`, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You should be able to identify the correct `<td>` element with an XPath like this: `By.xpath("//*[id='transactionGridControls']//td[text()='17']")`. That might make your code easier. And as @Richard said, you should be able to click it, even if it's not a link. Mind you, only if JS is executed; are you sure this is the case?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the case.  I did an edit (when it wasn't edit locked) and saw that the 17 and 18 were both contained in `td`s, that had javascript that fired onclick.

Comment: I checked and getting the unable to locate element exception:    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[id='transactionGridControls']//td[text()='17']"}